# How to return a concatenated list in python?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a function that takes a list and returns a concatenated string.

```
stringList = ["hello", "world"]
for string in stringList():
    #concatenate all strings in list
return newString
```

Expected output should be `"helloworld"`

My original idea was:

```
for string in stringList():
    string = string + ""
return string
```

However, this would only return the last element of a list. I'm not sure how to fix this. Also, I cannot use the print function and simply do:

```
print(string, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the inbuilt function of python strings called [join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
string = "".join(stringList)
```

Comment: @fen1x Sorry, but this most certainly does answer the question. It may not be a great answer, but the code solves the OP's problem.

Comment: @fen1x how about now? It would help if you could specify why you think this does not provide an answer to the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
"".join(stringList)
```